Removing white spaces in a histogram?
I came across this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648895/why-does-fair-random-process-lead-to-unfair-result/5001301#5001301 in which someone was interested in simulating a game where two players randomly give each other money.
Using R, I tried to simulate multiple trajectories of this game to look at the distributions of different metrics:
    library(ggplot2)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(gridExtra)
    library(future)
    library(furrr)
    library(parallel)
    
    n_cores <- detectCores() - 1  
    plan(multisession, workers = n_cores)


run_money_simulation <- function(n_sims, n_exchanges, player_a_start, player_b_start) {
    set.seed(123) 
    
    sims_per_core <- ceiling(n_sims / n_cores)
    
    simulate_exchange <- function(n_exchanges, player_a_start, player_b_start) {
        person_a <- numeric(n_exchanges + 1)
        person_b <- numeric(n_exchanges + 1)
        
        person_a[1] <- player_a_start
        person_b[1] <- player_b_start
        
        for(i in 2:(n_exchanges + 1)) {
            change <- sample(c(-1, 1), 1)
            person_a[i] <- person_a[i-1] + change
            person_b[i] <- person_b[i-1] - change
        }
        
        return(list(
            final_diff = person_a[n_exchanges + 1] - person_b[n_exchanges + 1],
            max_diff = max(abs(person_a - person_b)),
            max_amount = max(c(max(person_a), max(person_b))),
            min_amount = min(c(min(person_a), min(person_b)))
        ))
    }
    
    start_time <- Sys.time()
    
    results <- future_map(1:n_sims, function(x) {
        simulate_exchange(n_exchanges, player_a_start, player_b_start)
    }, .options = furrr_options(seed = TRUE))
    
    end_time <- Sys.time()
    time_taken <- difftime(end_time, start_time, units = "secs")
 
    
    final_diffs <- sapply(results, `[[`, "final_diff")
    max_diffs <- sapply(results, `[[`, "max_diff")
    max_amounts <- sapply(results, `[[`, "max_amount")
    min_amounts <- sapply(results, `[[`, "min_amount")
    
    plot_data <- tibble(
        final_diff = final_diffs,
        max_diff = max_diffs,
        max_amount = max_amounts,
        min_amount = min_amounts
    ) %>%
        pivot_longer(everything(), 
                     names_to = "metric", 
                     values_to = "value")
    
    main_plot <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = value)) +
        geom_histogram(bins = 50, aes(fill = metric), color = "white", alpha = 0.7) +
        facet_wrap(~metric, scales = "free", ncol = 2) +
        scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "red", "green4", "purple")) +
        labs(title = paste("Money Exchange Simulation Results\n",
                           "Starting amounts: A =", player_a_start, ", B =", player_b_start),
             subtitle = paste("Number of simulations:", n_sims, 
                              "| Exchanges per simulation:", n_exchanges,
                              "\nProcessed using", n_cores, "CPU cores in", 
                              round(time_taken, 2), "seconds"),
             x = "Value",
             y = "Count") +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
    
    
    print(main_plot)
    
    
    invisible(list(
        final_diffs = final_diffs,
        max_diffs = max_diffs,
        max_amounts = max_amounts,
        min_amounts = min_amounts,
        parameters = list(
            n_sims = n_sims,
            n_exchanges = n_exchanges,
            player_a_start = player_a_start,
            player_b_start = player_b_start,
            n_cores = n_cores,
            processing_time = time_taken
        )
    ))
}

When I call the function:
run_money_simulation(100000, 100, 100, 100)

I get the following results:

I am just wondering - is there something I can do in ggplot that detects a scale break format such that the white spaces in these charts will be removed?

I'm not clear what you want. You just want to skip sections of the x-axis? What exactly are you trying to communicate via the plot? If you don't have a consistent scale, it's much harder to interpret the data. If this question is about plotting, it's a bit overkill to include a multithreaded simulation that needs to be run just to test the plotting. I think you just have discrete outcomes rather than continuous which a histogram assumes. Try bins=40.

alternatively, switch to geom_density()

Since your data is discrete, maybe use binwidth = 1 instead of specifying the number of bins, which can create bin spacings that don't align to integer values.

The problem is that you are using the wrong kind of graph.  Histograms are for continuous data, and your data appear to be discrete.

@user2554330 There is no reason that histograms cannot be made from discrete integer data it is just that the bin size must be an exact integer wide. The OP appears to have 14 bins over a range of 50 ~ 3.571429 channels per bin. I am at a loss to explain the empty gaps in his histograms (worst that should happen is some get 4 channels added in and most get 3 channels). Perhaps the OP could provide his raw data after setting bin width to 4 (ie range of 200 with say 50 bins). ie Width exactly 4 channels.

@MartinBrown:  you can draw a histogram, but it's not a good representation of the data.  The actual final_diff values are always divisible by 4, but the graph suggests all values are possible.  He should use geom_bar(), not geom_histogram().  BTW, he did provide all the data, it's all simulated in the function he showed.

The problem is that you have discrete data.  Histograms are a kind of density estimate, designed for continuous data that actually has a density.
Looking at the top left figure final_diff, the data being shown is always a multiple of 4.  Since your bin width is slightly smaller than 4, a couple of bins completely miss the data.  You could avoid the gaps by setting the bin width to 4, but that's not the best solution.  The best solution is to use a display that is designed for discrete data.
The usual display for this kind of discrete data is a bar plot showing counts of each observed value.  You can get that in ggplot2 using geom_bar() instead of geom_histogram.  For example,

#  ... unchanged code deleted ...

  main_plot <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = value)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = metric)) +
    facet_wrap(~metric, scales = "free", ncol = 2) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "red", "green4", "purple")) +
    labs(title = paste("Money Exchange Simulation Results\n",
                       "Starting amounts: A =", player_a_start, ", B =", player_b_start),
         subtitle = paste("Number of simulations:", n_sims, 
                          "| Exchanges per simulation:", n_exchanges,
                          "\nProcessed using", n_cores, "CPU cores in", 
                          round(time_taken, 2), "seconds"),
         x = "Value",
         y = "Count") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
  
##  ... more unchanged code ...


Created on 2024-11-21 with reprex v2.1.1
This looks uglier than a histogram, but it is more faithful to the data.  And it's less ugly in a higher resolution display, where you can see that all the bars and spaces between them are the same width.

thank you for your answer! I disagree with one thing - I do not think it looks uglier than a histogram :) it looks really beautiful! :)

Try adding xlim(c(<lower_limit>, <upper_limit>)). From there, you can create another function to find where the 90th percentile (or another threshold) of your data lies - input that into your upper or lower limits.
